# Query related record and do some calculation from it inside query in laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, group-by

I am using laravel in my development and I have a database which look something like this.

**Seller Table:**

| id | name | position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | supervisor |
| 2 | michael | supervisor |
| 3 | ved | area manager |
| 4 | menz | manager |
| 5 | jun | clerk |

**Seller Sales Table:**

| id | seller_id | month | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | january | 5000 |
| 2 | 1 | february | 10000 |
| 3 | 2 | january | 1000 |
| 4 | 2 | february | 1000 |
| 5 | 3 | february | 1000 |

In my code, what I want to accomplish is to group seller table by its position. In addition, I also need to count how many seller has reach 1000 from its previous sale. In this example, the sample output looks like this.

RESULT:

| position | total count | has Reach 1000 sales from previous sale | has not Reach 1000 sales from previous sale |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| supervisor | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| area manager | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| manager | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| clerk | 1 | 0 | 1 |

My question is, is it possible to achieve this using query alone ? or I really need to add additional logic for this ? At  the moment the database is already connected using one-to-many relationship. My sample query looks like this

```
      $seller = Seller::with(['sales' => function ($query)use ($dateForCondition){
                                $query->orderBy('date', 'desc')
                               ->where('date', '<=', $dateForCondition)
                               ->limit(2);
                             }])
```

If it is possible using query alone, Can you please give me some idea about it ? If it is not possible using query alone, and I need to manually loop all the record and add some conditions and variables to group by position, I have thousands of records and I am afraid that I might hit some limitations during the process. Please help thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you pretty much have all the data you need to do the work in blade,

```
$salesPeopleGrouped = Seller::with(['sales' => function ($query) use ($dateForCondition) {
    $query->orderBy('date', 'desc')
        ->where('date', '<=', $dateForCondition)
        ->limit(2); // Not sure why you are setting a limmit.
}])->groupBy('position');


<table class="s-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align: left;">position</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">total count</th>
            <th style="text-align: right;">has Reach 1000 sales from previous sale</th>
            <th style="text-align: right;">has not Reach 1000 sales from previous sale</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($salesPeopleGrouped as $position => $salesPeople)
    @php
        $over = $salesPeople->countBy(function ($person) {
            return $person->sales >= 1000;
        });
    @endphp
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: left;">{{ $position }}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $salesPeople->count() }}</td>
        <td style="text-align: right;">{{ $over }}</td>
        <td style="text-align: right;">{{ $salesPeople->count() - $over }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you so much mate. I really appreciate this answer. However, I think there is some part which I did not clearly explain in my question. What I want is to subtract the current month and the previous month to check if I reach 1000 sales from the previous. that is also the reason why I limit 2 in my subquery.

Comment: Ah no worries, So are your months which are stored in the DB just plain ol strings or are they actual date fields. @Hope

Comment: actually in my real data, its a date type the data I give is just a sample data.

Comment: In addition your answer will give an error since we are using 'with' and 'group by' at the same time.